# How to load dyanmic data related to a product in a modal

Tags: reactjs

I am using react and on page load, it display list of products and I have a modal, which I want to open on each click of a product with its related data. I cannot understand how to make every displayed list of product such that everytime I click on the relative data shows. As `<Link to="#">` and a action on called upon click, how can I get pass data from App.js to Modal.js or I am thinking wrong?

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true)

const handleOpen = () => setIsOpen(true);

<div className='movie'>
  <Modal isOpen={isOpen} setIsOpen={setIsOpen} text='' />
  {movies.length > 0 &&
    movies.map((data) => {
      return <Library key={data.id} {...data} searchTerm={searchTerm} />;
    })}
    <button type='button' onClick={() => handleOpen()}>Open modal</button>
</div>;
```

Modal.jsx

```
export default function Index({children, isOpen, setIsOpen, text}) {

  return (
    isOpen && (
      <div className='modalContainer'>
      <div className="modal">
        <div className="close">
          <button onClick={()=>{
            setIsOpen(false)
          }}>close</button>
        </div>
        {text}
      </div>
    </div>
    )    
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of handling this problem is to save the data of movie in a state and then pass that state to Modal. It would be something like this.

```js
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);
const [selectedMovie, setSelectedMovie] = useState(null);
const handleOpen = () => setIsOpen(true);

<div className="movie">
  <Modal isOpen={isOpen} setIsOpen={setIsOpen} text="" selectedMovie={selectedMovie}/>
  {movies.length > 0 &&
    movies.map((data) => {
      return (
        <Library
          key={data.id}
          {...data}
          searchTerm={searchTerm}
          onClick={() => setSelectedMovie(data)}
        />
      );
    })}
  <button type="button" onClick={() => handleOpen()}>
    Open modal
  </button>
</div>;
```

Modal.js

```js
export default function Index({
  children,
  isOpen,
  setIsOpen,
  text,
  selectedMovie,
}) {
  // do whatever with the selected movie here
  return (
    isOpen && (
      <div className="modalContainer">
        <div className="modal">
          <div className="close">
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                setIsOpen(false);
              }}
            >
              close
            </button>
          </div>
          {text}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks, this has troubled me a lot. Any good resource to read from?